# Ajax call not working on Android 8 built with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have set a cheap certificate from Digicert on my server but I think it has an intermediate certificate.
When testing my application on PhoneGap CLI using

```
phonegap serve
```

Ajax call to my server is working. But when the apk is built on PhoneGap, it is stuck on ajax call.
How can I check if there is a problem? on Adobe PhoneGap build logs said it is build successfully.

Also, my server application is listening to 4000 port. Anyone can tell me how to fix this?

[image: SSL Checker result]

Comment: would you please edit to share your server public address? I'm assuming that's the same address you have in your app.

Comment: have you tested both with debug build and release build?

Comment: @Fabio, how it is same address in my app? my app is built on phonegap.

Comment: @MDP, I tried it on phonegap cli and it is working. But when I build it on adobe phonegap, it is not working. If I build it on adobe phonegap with lower API and android version, it is working.

Comment: I think it's related to minify feature of proguard. add annotation `@keep` to your object classes. see if it solves your problem

Comment: @M D P, can you provide where is the object classes?

Comment: @JMA can you check android log cat and tell if you are getting `IOException java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to * not permitted` this exception because  Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Comment: @arpan can you provide path for the log?

Comment: @JMA you can use logcat of the Android Studio or you can use the command-line tool https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat